# identify and process overlapping rows in awk

Tags: awk

I have the following sorted file [sorted by sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n]:
start and end coordinates are defined by col2 & col3, value is defined by col4:

```
chr11   45643103    45643104    0.005
chr11   45643104    45643108    0
chr11   45643107    45643109    0.007
chr11   45643108    45643110    0.107
```

and I'd like to use an awk procedure that would identify overlapping regions such as in these two rows

```
chr11   45643104    45643108    0
chr11   45643107    45643109    0.007
```

and will output the widest stretch, obtaining the highest value (from col4) throughout the stretch 
so as per this example would output the following:

```
chr11   45643103    45643104    0.005
chr11   45643104    45643109    0.007
chr11   45643108    45643110    0.107
```

Comment: And what, in your sample data defines "overlapping"? I don't see much difference between line 2 and 3 vs line 1 and 2 (for example). Good luck.

Comment: Why not `chr11   45643104   45643110    0.107`?  It should be the widest stretch.

Comment: Edit your question to show your algorithm in pseudo-code and we can help you translate it into awk.

Answer (score 0):

Start with something like this and think about state machines.

```
chr==$1 && $2>=stop && !run {
    print prev;print;stop=$3;run=1
}
chr==$1 && $2>=stop && run {
    print;stop=$3;
}
chr==$1 && $2<stop {
    prev=$0;stop=$3;run=0;
}
chr!=$1  {
    chr=$1;prev=$0;stop=$3;run=0;
}
```

(untested)